# Taylor expansion of function of inverse matrix

Tags: matrices

Given the function $f(K)=K^{-1} ; domf= S^{n}_{++}$, i.e the set of positive definite matrices. So this is a convex function with respect of $K$. I want to find a Taylor expansion around $K_{0} \in  S^{n}_{++} $ of this function.

I know that the first derivative is $\frac{dK^{-1}}{dK} = - (K^{-T}) \otimes  K^{-1}$. What is the formula for the second derivative of $f(K)$.

Using the first and the second derivative, what is the Taylor expansion for the function $f(K)$. It may look like :

$$ K^{-1} =K^{-1}_{0} +(K-K_{0})\frac{dK_{0}^{-1}}{dK_{0}}+..$$
What should be the product between a matrix $(K-K_{0})$ that has size $n \times n$ with a matrix $\frac{dK_{0}^{-1}}{dK_{0}}$ with size $(n^2 \times n^2)$ here?

Thanks